# Angular 5 cli test coverage - branch not covered

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli, angular5, istanbul

[image: branch not covered]

How to cover @Component styleURls and templateUrl?
Highlighted by yellow is "branch not covered"!

```
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue. Removing `--source-map=false` from my package.json task worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem.

Based on some suggestions from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5526), I was able to fix it by targeting ES6 in the **tsconfig.spec.json** file. Here is my file in full:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The coverage highlighting now appears to be correct, and there are no issues highlighted in the @Component section.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `ng test --code-coverage` command.